# How to change a route in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Now I have address like `domain/:board_id/:theme_id/`. But I want to create something like `domain/:board_name/:theme_id`. What shoud I do?

Comment: No, only second variant, through :board_name

Comment: Add `match 'domain/:board_name/:theme_id' => 'themes#show', :as => :domain_board_theme` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match ':board_name/:them_id' => 'some_controller#index'
```

Then you can use ActionView helpers:

```
link_to 'Some link', :board_name => 'some_name', :them_id => 12
```

You will have the link your_domain/some_name/12

In the controller you can get that parameters as:

```
params[:them_id]
params[:board_name]
```